# omniauth mock facebook response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rspec, mocking, omniauth

I'm want to test my login through facebook. Im using pure omniauth, w/o Devise. I check the wiki page and do following:

helper for request specs

```
module IntegrationSpecHelper
  def login_with_oauth(service = :facebook)
    visit "/auth/#{service}"
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.include IntegrationSpecHelper, :type => :request
    end

    Capybara.default_host = 'http://example.org'
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
    :provider => 'facebook',
    :uid => '12345',
    :user_info => {
        :name => 'dpsk'
      }
})
```

my spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'facebook' do
  it "should login with facebook", :js => true do
    login_with_oauth

    visit '/'
    page.should have_content("dpsk")
  end
end


#OmniAuth routes
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
  match "/signin" => "sessions#signin", :as => :signin
  match "/auth/failure" => "sessions#failure", :as => :auth_failure
```

But in spec nothing returns instead of my mock i got an error:

```
Failure/Error: visit "/auth/facebook"
     You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Where is my error?

Comment: if i comment out part with my mock and host(left only enable_test_mode = true) than behavior didnt change. seems like omniauth just didnt see my mock :|

Comment: What does your sessions controller and user model look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was in the mock, its has wrong structure.

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
  'user_info' => {
    'name' => 'Mario Brothers',
    'image' => '',
    'email' => 'dpsk@email.ru' },
  'uid' => '123545',
  'provider' => 'facebook',
  'credentials' => {'token' => 'token'}
}
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that this should be in the AuthHash structure. Just initialize `OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({THE HASH YOU HAVE})`

Answer (score 0):

This structure worked for me (December 2016)

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  'provider' => 'facebook', 
  'uid' => '123545', 
  'info' => {
    'email' => 'dpsk@email.ru', 
    'name' => 'Mario Brothers', 
    'image' => '' }, 
  'credentials'=> {
    'token'=> '12345', 
    'expires_at' => 1486718672, 
    'expires' => true }, 
  'extra' => {
    'raw_info' => {
        'email' => 'dpsk@email.ru', 
        'name' => 'Mario Brothers', 
        'id' => '12345' }
    }
})
```